# Disambiguating namespaces in generated XAML code

Tags: xaml, c++-cx

I have a `Page` that imports controls from a library like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Foo.Bar.SomePage"
    xmlns:myNamespace="using:Bar.Controls">

    <myNamespace:SomeControl x:Name="someControl">
        <!-- snip -->
   </myNamespace:SomeControl> 
</Page>
```

As you can see here, the page is declared in the `::Foo::Bar` namespace, while `SomeControl` is declared in the `::Bar` namespace. The problem I face is that Visual Studio generates this code:

```
namespace Bar {
    namespace Controls {
        ref class SomeControl;
    }
}

namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        partial ref class SomePage : /* ... */
        {
            /* ... */
            private: Bar::SomeControl^ someControl;
        };
    }
}
```

The field definition `Bar::SomeControl^ someControl` tries to select `::Foo::Bar::SomeControl`  instead of `::Bar::SomeControl` because Visual Studio doesn't  fully-qualify it.

Is this by design (is there a way to phrase the `using:` URI in such a way that it will fully-qualify the name), or is this a bug? How can I work around that?

I think that I could convince people to make an exception to the namespace structure for this specific class, but it would be much simpler if there was an in-code solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, right now I'm using this kludge before #including the g.h file, but it's not super pretty:

```
namespace Foo
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        typedef ::Bar::SomeControl SomeControl;
    }
}
```

It introduces the control into the (incorrect) namespace so that it works even though the XAML code generator gets it wrong.